# Validate date from mongo greater than 24 hrs

Tags: mongodb, express

> how can i validate a field form mongodb storing datetime is greater
>   than 24 hrs.I have to validate it is less than 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all of the documents in a collection that were created 24 hours ago, then each document in the collection has to have a field representing the date it was created:

```
{
    "title" : "A blog post",
    "author" : "vmr",
    "content" : "...",
    "created_on" : new Date();
}

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Then run this command to get documents which are older than 24hrs:

```
db.posts.find({created_on: {$lt: date}});
```

Hope this helps.